# Module 'grpc' logger enabled for log level 'ERROR' when running docker-compose up command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run the `docker-compose up` command, but I'm getting an error from the grpc logger. I'm following the steps given on [this website](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-chaincode-for-java-developers/index.html) and I'm stuck at step 4 (Start the blockchain network).

I tried various images for the fabric peer, for example:

- *hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.1*
- *hyperledger/fabric-peer*
- *hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.0-rc1*
- etc.

Here is my *docker-compose.yml* file for the fabric image:

```
vp0:image: "hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.1"
```

I get the following error when running `docker-compose up`:

> DEBU 1a9 Module 'grpc' logger enabled for log level 'ERROR'

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This is not an ERROR. It means your log level will be set as ERROR which means only the error log will be logged.

Answer (score 0):

looks more like a statement than a real ERROR. If you run `docker ps` are your containers running?

Comment: is there any way to create blockchain network and run it