# Manifest not found on docker composer even if the tag exists

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this YML file

> docker-compose-testing.yml

with docker compose configuration:

```
version: '3'                                                
services:                                                   
  nginx_testing:                                            
    image: MY_SERVER_IP:5000/lens/nginx_testing:${VERSION}  
    volumes:                                                
      - certs:/etc/letsencrypt                              
      - certs-data:/data/letsencrypt                        
    ports:                                                  
      - 80:80                                               
      - 443:443                                             
    depends_on:                                             
      - ws_server                                           
      - translator                                          
      - auth                                                
  ws_server:                                                
    image: MY_SERVER_IP:5000/lens/ws_server:${VERSION}      
  worker:                                                   
    image: MY_SERVER_IP:5000/lens/worker:${VERSION}         
    depends_on:                                             
      - ws_server                                           
  translator:                                               
    image: MY_SERVER_IP:5000/lens/translator:${VERSION}     
  auth:                                                     
    image: MY_SERVER_IP:5000/lens/auth:${VERSION}           
    volumes:                                                
      - auth-data:/usr/src/app/data                         

volumes:                                                    
  certs:                                                    
  certs-data:                                               
  auth-data:
```

Normally, I use this command to apply the above configuration:

> export VERSION=578d8de && envsubst < docker-compose-testing.yml | docker-compose -f - pull && envsubst < docker-compose-testing.yml | docker-compose -f - -p PROJECT_NAME up -d --no-build --scale worker=5

Now, when I execute this command (above) the console show this error:

> Pulling translator (MY_SERVER_IP:5000/lens/translator:578d8de)...
>   ERROR: manifest for MY_SERVER_IP:5000/lens/translator:578d8de not found

The response for one similar question below says that the tag do not exists:

[Error response from daemon: manifest for ibmblockchain/fabric-peer:latest not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45952630/error-response-from-daemon-manifest-for-ibmblockchain-fabric-peerlatest-not-fo)

But when I list the images with command:

> docker images | grep 578d8de

Console show this output proving that the tag exists:

```
MY_SERVER_IP:5000/lens/auth            578d8de             8103c4d63870        2 hours ago         195MB
MY_SERVER_IP:5000/lens/nginx_testing   578d8de             578d8dead150        4 hours ago         235MB
MY_SERVER_IP:5000/lens/translator      578d8de             e9eb25fa0aef        5 hours ago         185MB
MY_SERVER_IP:5000/lens/ws_server       578d8de             92b1d1a4cee9        5 hours ago         177MB
MY_SERVER_IP:5000/lens/worker          578d8de             22a935deba5c        7 days ago          175MB
```

Some extra details:

1. The server (MY_SERVER_IP) has a docker registry listening on 5000 port.
2. The image with version tag 578d8de was uploaded to the server not with registry, but with the "docker save" and "scp" command on the dev machine, and "docker load" on the server.

Any idea why this error is occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is happenning when I send image with `scp` command to server and load the image to docker.

How I don't use `docker push` to the registry, the image don't exists in registry.

So when `docker-compose pull` execute, don't find image on registry and dispatch the error.